# if the first is true don't run the second

Tags: java

Hello I'm new to Java and after reading a little about it I tried to make little program. The program contain two if stacks and I want if the one resolves the program to end and not read the second at all.
Here is the code I came up with:

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

```
     String independent1 = "money";
     String independent2 = "succes";
     String independent3 = "career";
     String userInput; 
     int randomNumber;
     System.out.println("I'm listening mortal. Pick your topic.");

     userInput = myScanner.next();



          if(independent1.equals(userInput))
            System.out.println("You should rely on yourself more than                  on mystic forces like me");
          if(independent2.equals(userInput))
                System.out.println("You should rely on yourself more than on mystic forces like me");
          if(independent3.equals(userInput))
                System.out.println("You should rely on yourself more than on mystic forces like me");

          Random myRandom = new Random();
            randomNumber =myRandom.nextInt(100)+1;    
                  if (randomNumber >= 50){
          System.out.println(randomNumber);
           System.out.println("Yes");
         } else {
          System.out.println(randomNumber);
          System.out.println("No!");
```

I want if the "independent if" is true the program to end and not run the second one, can someone help me?

Comment: Take a look at [if-then-else statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: how about an "else if()" instead of many "if"? if(independent1.equals(userInput))
            System.out.println("bla");
else if(independent2.equals(userInput))
            System.out.println("foo");

Answer (score 3):

Use an `if / else if`

```
if(independent1.equals(userInput)){
....
} else if(independent2.equals(userInput)){
....
} else if(independent3.equals(userInput)){
...
}
```

if you use [java 1.7](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/) you can also use switch statements with strings. They were introduced with [JSR 334](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=334).

```
switch(userInput){
    case "money":
        ....
        break;
    case "succes":
        ....
        break;
    case "career":
        ....
        break;
}
```

Comment: Go more far with `switch`

Comment: @nachokk if/else is more flexible, and both are useful. Your comment isn't productive.

Comment: @Zaphod42 in which way is more `flexible`? i think it was cause he edit..+1 for edit

Answer (score 0):

You can also use switch case:

```
switch(expression){
    case value :
       //Statements
       break; //optional
    case value :
       //Statements
       break; //optional
    //You can have any number of case statements.
    default : //Optional
       //Statements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try it like following**

```
boolean b = false;
      if(independent1.equals(userInput)){
        System.out.println("You should rely on yourself more than                  on    mystic forces like me");
 b = true;
     } else if(independent2.equals(userInput)) {
            System.out.println("You should rely on yourself more than on mystic forces like me");
 b = true;
      }else if(independent3.equals(userInput)){
 b = true;
            System.out.println("You should rely on yourself more than on mystic forces   like me");
} 



if(!b){
  Random myRandom = new Random();
     randomNumber =myRandom.nextInt(100)+1;    
          if (randomNumber >= 50){
  System.out.println(randomNumber);
   System.out.println("Yes");
 } else {
  System.out.println(randomNumber);
  System.out.println("No!");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the following might be suitable.

```
userInput = myScanner.nextLine(); // Entire line maybe?

if (userInput.contains(independent1)) {
    ...
} else if (userInput.contains(independent2)) {
    ...
} else if (userInput.contains(independent3)) {
    ...
} else {
    // Maybe you meant the rest to go in here, as alternative.
    Random ...
}
```